# I am having trouble creating a proper trigger in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a trigger on `tplayoffStatus` so that teams are not allowed to be inserted into the table with more than one loss. When inserting a value into the table `tplayoffStatus` the error I keep getting is

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can anyone help me with this? Is my `SELECT` statement wrong for returning multiple values in the column losses?

SQL Server 2014 table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tcollegeFootballTeams
(
    TeamAbbreviation varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    City varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    State varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Wins int NOT NULL,
    Losses int NOT NULL
)  

CREATE TABLE tplayoffStatus
(
    TeamName varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamAbbreviation varchar(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tcollegeFootballTeams(TeamAbbreviation)
); 

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgNoPlayoffForYou] 
ON [dbo].[tplayoffStatus]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @Losses INT
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(30)

    SELECT @Losses = (SELECT Losses 
                      FROM dbo.tcollegeFootballTeams 
                      WHERE (Losses > 1))

    IF (@Losses = 'True') 
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'You may not enter the playoffs with more than 1 loss'
        PRINT @ErrorMessage
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('OSU', 'THE Ohio State University', 'Columbus', 'OH', 10, 2)
```

[Results][2]

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses  )
VALUES ('BAMA', 'Alabama', 'Tuscaloosa', 'AL', 12, 0)
```

[Results][3]

Query 3:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses  )
VALUES ('UGA', 'Georgia', 'Athens', 'GA', 11, 1)
```

[Results][4]

Query 4:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('CLEM', 'Clemson', 'Clemson', 'SC', 11, 1)
```

[Results][5]

Query 5:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('WIS', 'Wisconsin', 'Madison', 'WI', 11, 1)
```

[Results][6]

Query 6:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('ND', 'Notre Dame', 'South Bend', 'IN', 10, 2)
```

[Results][7]

Query 7:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('OKLA', 'Oklahoma', 'Norman', 'OK', 10, 2)
```

[Results][8]

Query 8:

```
INSERT INTO tcollegeFootballTeams (TeamAbbreviation, TeamName, City, State, Wins, Losses)
VALUES ('MIAF', 'Miami of Florida', 'Coral Gables', 'FL', 10, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your trigger is wrong. You need to query the `inserted` table for the records inserted and join to the `tcollegeFootballTeams` table for `Losses`

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgNoPlayoffForYou] ON [dbo].[tplayoffStatus]
AFTER INSERT
AS

    IF EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   inserted i
                  INNER JOIN dbo.tcollegeFootballTeams t 
                  ON i.TeamAbbreviation = t.TeamAbbreviation
           WHERE  t.Losses > 1
       )
    BEGIN 
           SET  @ErrorMessage = 'You may not enter the playoffs with more than 1 loss'
           Print @ErrorMessage
           Rollback Transaction
    END
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I didnt even think to use a select statment like that but it totally makes sense. I clearly need to work on that aspect of my SQL.